# Use both, SQL Server Compact and SQL Server with Entity Framework simultaneously

Tags: entity-framework

I have a web application that already works well with *SQL Server Compact*. Now, I am adding a *SQL Server* model. If I just simple pass the *SQL Server* connection string to the `DbContext` instance, I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'application name'.

I can fix *SQL Server* (but break *SQL Server Compact*) it if I change the *web.config* from:

```
 <entityFramework>
-  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
     <parameters>
-      <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
     </parameters>
   </defaultConnectionFactory>
   <providers>
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
   </providers>
 </entityFramework>
```

To:

```
 <entityFramework>
+  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
     <parameters>
+      <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
     </parameters>
   </defaultConnectionFactory>
   <providers>
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
   </providers>
 </entityFramework>
```

How can I keep both working?  I think I need to add some `<context>` tags in the *web.config*, but I have not got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I left the *web.config* as it originally was with the default *SQL Server Compact* connection factory. The only difference is that I added the *SQL Server* provider, like this:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
+     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Then, in my model context class, I call the `DbContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)` constructor like this:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base(GetConnection(), true)
    {
    }

    private static DbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = "Application Name=EntityFramework;Password=foo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=bar;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=foo.database.windows.net";
        return connection;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now I can use multiple providers.